# Oracle SQL Cumulative Product

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I have a somewhat similar question to: [MySQL cumulative product group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48970227/mysql-cumulative-product-group-by/) but I'm unable to get the proposed solution to work for my situation.

I have 5 month over month percentage change values that I want to apply to a static value. I want the resulting value to be cumulative for all months.

| Report_Month | PCT_Change | Initial_Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8/1/2021 | 0.1202 | 0.88 |
| 9/1/2021 | -.0426 |  |
| 10/1/2021 | -0.0794 |  |
| 11/1/2021 | 0.0726 |  |
| 12/1/2021 | 0.1182 |  |

If I were calculating this in Excel the out put would look like:

| Report_Month | PCT_Change | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8/1/2021 | 0.1202 | 0.985776 |
| 9/1/2021 | -.0426 | 0.943781942 |
| 10/1/2021 | -0.0794 | 0.868845656 |
| 11/1/2021 | 0.0726 | 0.931923851 |
| 12/1/2021 | 0.1182 | 1.04207725 |

However, when I use the exp(sum(ln(x))) method that's not what I'm getting. This is the output using exp(sum(ln(0.88*(1+pct_change))) over (order by report_month)).

| Report_Month | PCT_Change | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8/1/2021 | 0.1202 | 0.9857 |
| 9/1/2021 | -.0426 | 0.8305 |
| 10/1/2021 | -0.0794 | 0.6728 |
| 11/1/2021 | 0.0726 | 0.6351 |
| 12/1/2021 | 0.1182 | 0.6249 |

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `Initial_Value` must be multiplied to the result of the `SUM()` window function, so the correct expression is:

```
0.88 * EXP(SUM(LN((1 + pct_change))) OVER (ORDER BY report_month))
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b0a71284279434e183b4097f7e7ea6ec).

Comment: Perfect! This is why I love the Stack Overflow community. Stupid simple mistake, but I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure it out for hours. Thanks @forpas!