# SQL Server Query for BOM Quantity

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I think this is an issue of CAST correctly on q but not sure how.  Quantity is defined as (numeric(24, 5), not null)  Thank you for your help.

```
with all_item_counts as 
(
    select 
        ParentId, Id, Quantity as q, 0 as level 
    from 
        dbo.MBOM
    union all 
    select 
        all_item_counts. ParentId, dbo.MBOM.Id, Quantity * q, level + 1 
    from 
        all_item_counts
    join 
        dbo.MBOM on dbo.MBOM. ParentId = all_item_counts.Id
)
select 
    ParentId, Id, sum(q) 
from 
    all_item_counts
group by 
    ParentId, Id
```

I get this error:

> Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "q" of recursive query "all_item_counts".

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Change the anchor to `CAST(Quantity as numeric(38,6)) as q`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure why you have the multiply in the first place. If you want the total for each root, try this:

```
with all_item_counts as 
(
    select 
        Id As RootId, ParentId, Id, Quantity as q, 0 as level 
    from 
        dbo.MBOM WHERE ParentId is NULL
    union all 
    select 
         all_item_counts.RootId,dbo.MBOM.ParentId,dbo.MBOM.Id, dbo.MBOM.Quantity, level + 1 
    from 
        all_item_counts
    join 
        dbo.MBOM on dbo.MBOM. ParentId = all_item_counts.Id
)
select 
    RootId, ParentId, Id, q
from 
    all_item_counts
```

That gives me a result like this:

| RootId | ParentId | Id | q |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | 1 | 1.00000 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2.00000 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4.00000 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | 8.00000 |
| 1 | 4 | 5 | 16.00000 |
| 1 | 5 | 6 | 32.00000 |

Which you can easily group and sum by RootId.
If you really need the product [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48970227/mysql-cumulative-product-group-by/52373745#52373745) has a technique for doing that involving LOG and EXP functions